# private variables in class don't show

Tags: php, class, oop, magic-methods

so i have a piece of code which somehow doesn't work. I'm really banging my head against it also because i've used it so many times before that i really don't know what the issue could be.

I've set a config class with language variables and i set these variables in the constructor. if i use them in the constructor they work, but when i try to call them from outside the constructor in a other class which inherits the config class, they show up empty. this is my code:

```
    <?php
// Start de sessie
ob_start();
session_start();

// Locate application path
define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
define('ROOT', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));

function __autoload($className) {
    // Add classes
    if (file_exists(ROOT . DS .'classes'. DS . ucfirst(strtolower($className)) . '.php')) {
        require_once (ROOT . DS .'classes'. DS . ucfirst(strtolower($className)) . '.php');
    } else {
        die('Class not found ('.$className.')');
    }
}


if(!isset($_SESSION['lang'])){
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'nl';
}
if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $lang = $_GET['lang'];
    if($lang != 'en' && $lang != 'nl') {
        $_SESSION['lang'] = 'nl';
    }else {
        $_SESSION['lang'] = $lang;
    }
}
class Config {

    //declare variables
    private $kmailtext;
    private $kslidertext;
    private $kcontactbutton;
    private $kofferstitle;
    private $kofferssecondtitle;
    private $khomebanner1;
    private $khomebanner2;
    private $khomebanner3;
    private $khomebanner4;
    private $kmaintenancetitle;
    private $kmaintenancetitle1;
    private $kmaintenancetitle2;

    function __construct() {
        if($_SESSION['lang'] == 'nl') {
            //    NEDERLANSE TEXT
            $this->kmailtext = "Mail ons";
            $this->kslidertext = "Karsten Installatie helpt u van A tot Z";
            $this->kcontactbutton = "contact";
            $this->kofferstitle = "CV-KETELS";
            $this->kofferssecondtitle = "Bekijk onze aanbiedingen uit onze selectie van CV-Ketels";
            $this->khomebanner1 = "CV Installatie";
            $this->khomebanner2 = "CV Onderhoud";
            $this->khomebanner3 = "Loodgieter";
            $this->khomebanner4 = "Advies";
            $this->kmaintenancetitle = "ONDERHOUDSCONTRACTEN";
            $this->kmaintenancetitle1 = "Onderhoudscontracten";
            $this->kmaintenancetitle2 = "Kiest u voor een onderhoudscontract, dan ben u zeker van deskundig onderhoud van uw cv-ketel en/of warmwaterinstallatie.";
        } else {
        //    ENGELSE VERTALING
            $this->kmailtext = "Mail us";
            $this->kslidertext = "Karsten Installatie helps u from A to Z";
            $this->kcontactbutton = "contact";
            $this->kofferstitle = "Boilers";
            $this->kofferssecondtitle = "Check our offers from our boiler selection";
            $this->khomebanner1 = "Boiler installation";
            $this->khomebanner2 = "Boiler maintenance";
            $this->khomebanner3 = "Plumber";
            $this->khomebanner4 = "Advice";
            $this->kmaintenancetitle = "MAINTENANCE CONTRACTS";
            $this->kmaintenancetitle1 = "Maintenance Contracts";
            print_r($this->kmaintenancetitle);
        }
    }

    public function __get($name) {
        return $this->$name;
    }

}

class someOtherClass extends Config {

     public function someFunction() {
         return $this->kmaintenancetitle;
     }

}

$someclass = someOtherClass();
echo $someclass->someFunction();
?>
```

Comment: Declare all variables public

Comment: They are declared as private so perhaps you would need to do `$config->__get('kmaintenancetitle');`

Comment: **echo $this->kmaintenancetitle;** is outside the scope

Comment: sorry that was an edit fail, i've actually used $config in my code and @RamRaider __GET is a magic method, it gets called when you try to access a private variable and returns it if you've set it up

Comment: Yeah, I know - I initially thought it just a single underscore, thus not a `magic` method

Comment: Aaaah ... now it makes a bit more sense - you're not invoking the `__get()` magic method there simply calling the class member directly... and since it's private it's out of scope. It'll work if you declare it as a `protected` class member in the parent class.

Comment: [Seems to work well enough](https://3v4l.org/v8LRE) (as long as you don't override `__get()` in the child class

Comment: If you have a `__get()` method defined in the child class, then that's the one that will be executed, so child class scope will apply (unless you call parent::__get($name)

Comment: OK - my previous comment can be safely ignored as it's demonstrably wrong... :)

Comment: [Demo with `__get()` being overridden in child class, but still being invoked](https://3v4l.org/FWcsp) Does this approach solve your problem?

Comment: My constructor overwrote the child constructor Thanks for the responses, fixed it now

Answer (score 2):

```
$config = new Config();
echo $this->kmaintenancetitle;
```

should be

```
$config = new Config();
echo $config->kmaintenancetitle;
```

and then it will invoke you magic getter successfully

Answer (score 1):

You have just forgotten the `new` in this line

```
$someclass = someOtherClass();
```

It should be

```
$someclass = new someOtherClass();
```

Then everything works. Although this only applies to the second version of your question, not the first!

Answer (score 0):

Declare config class properties as protected.

```
class Config {

//declare variables    
...
protected $kmaintenancetitle;
protected $kmaintenancetitle1;
protected $kmaintenancetitle2;
```

Comment: Makes absolutely no difference in this case